# Projection of a GPS point on a segment representing a trajectory

Tags: geometry, gps, coordinates, projection

Consider the A-B segment in the picture below; each extremity is a GPS point defined by latitude & longitude (the segment is actually an arc, as it lies on the earth surface).

Point C is not part of the segment. I would like to compute latitude and longitude for point P, i.e. the projection of point C on the A-B segment.

Is there a way to do that without moving to a local cartesian system (e.g. Lat/Long/Alt -> North/East/Down) and back? I would like to avoid it as the points are actually part of long routes spanning many kilometers, and a local cartesian system would not cover the full extent.

[image: <code>intersection</code>]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to find P point using combination of formulas from [latlong](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) page.

At first find `δ12` and `δ13`  - angular distances from start point to end and third point (Distance section)

Then bearings `θ13` and `θ12` from start point to the third point and end point (Bearing section)

Get cross-track angular distance

```
 δxt = asin( sin(δ13) ⋅ sin(θ13−θ12) )
```

Use it to get along-track angular distance

```
  δat = acos( cos(δ13) / cos(δxt) )
```

and calculate intermediate point P

```
a = sin(δ12 - δat) / sin δ12
b = sin(δat) / sin δ12
x = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ cos λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos λ2
y = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ sin λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin λ2
z = a ⋅ sin φ1 + b ⋅ sin φ2

φi = atan2(z, √x² + y²)
λi = atan2(y, x)
```